# How I do change the BIG image to the thumbnail images when I click the Color Swatches on the right?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

How I do change the BIG image to the thumbnail images when I click the Color Swatches on the right? I guess I need to map the thumbnail images to the color swatches?
Im hoping to loop through the thumbnail images when i click through the color swatches. so when you click the first color swatch, the BIG image will update to show the FIRST thumbnail and so forth

```js
let colorSwatch = document.querySelectorAll(".color-swatches");
let smallImg = document.getElementsByClassName("sec");

for(let i= 0; i <colorSwatch.length; i++){
  colorSwatch[i].addEventListener("click", changeColor);
  
}

function changeColor(){

  for (let a = 0; a < smallImg.length; a++){
  document.querySelector(".main-image").setAttribute("src",smallImg[a].getAttribute("src"));
    console.log(a);
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="image-container">
          <img
            src="https://source.unsplash.com/400x400/?stationery"
            class="item main-image"
          />
          <div class="secondary-image">
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/100x100/?pen"
              class="item sec item-1 active "
            />
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/100x100/?pencil"
              class="item sec item-2"
            />
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/100x100/?notepad"
              class="item sec item-3"
            />
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/100x100/?eraser"
              class="item sec item-4"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="product-info">
          <h1>Product Name</h1>
          <p>Product description goes here two line product description</p>
          <h3>Color</h3>
          <div class="color-swatches">
            <img src="color-swatch.svg" class="swatch color-1" />
            <img src="color-swatch.svg" class="swatch color-2" />
            <img src="color-swatch.svg" class="swatch color-3" />
            <img src="color-swatch.svg" class="swatch color-4" />
           
          </div>
          <h3>Quantity</h3>
          <div class="quantity">
            <!-- <svg>
              <ellipse cx="35" cy="35" rx="35" ry="35" />
            </svg> -->

            <img
              src="https://cdn.glitch.global/935c1b3a-2d6f-42b5-aab8-2ea9c89cca70/minus-circle.svg?v=1645435804825"
              id="minus-icon"
            />

            <h3 id="quantity-value">1</h3>
            <img
              src="https://cdn.glitch.global/935c1b3a-2d6f-42b5-aab8-2ea9c89cca70/plus-circle.svg?v=1645435811670"
              id="plus-icon"
            />
          </div>

          <button class="btn-primary add-to-cart-btn">Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: I dont see any color-swatches.

Comment: sorry, there is supposed to be color swatches to the right of the images - basically just 4 buttons

Comment: if you wanna some help, you should provide with the code missing, where's the ref for `color-swatches` class?

Comment: i am trying to edit the code, it is not letting me. give me one moment

Comment: @NineCattoRules I just updated the code - does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line: `document.querySelector(".main-image").setAttribute("src",smallImg[a].getAttribute("src"));` ...you select the source of your image that has `sec` as class, this means you get this source: `src="https://source.unsplash.com/100x100/?eraser"`.
So that's the problem, the `100x100`.

As a workaround you can use this CSS style:

```
img.item.main-image {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

...and change the source of your thumbnails like this:

```
https://source.unsplash.com/300x300/?eraser
```

Comment: So everytime i click on a color swatch, the BIG image is supposed to change into one of the small images. It's like when you visit a retailer website and click on the Color options, the product image would change to reflect the color you chose. it's like this amazon page: https://www.amazon.com/Fullgaden-iPad-Case-Lightweight-Translucent/dp/B081Y5D1B6/ref=asc_df_B081Y52YFY/?tag=&linkCode=df0&hvadid=416652333997&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=16181752784790518593&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9004380&hvtargid=pla-870060918174&ref=&adgrpid=100759324064&th=1

Comment: Im hoping to loop through the thumbnail images when i click through the color swatches.

Comment: @cool-peaches I'm talking about your code. For do something like that Amazon page you better have to look at something like [this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/fullscreen-lightbox-gallery.html)